# Javascript - FileReader how can I read and process each file at a time among multiple files

Tags: javascript, ajax, filereader, onload

I am trying let the user drop multiple excel file and extract desired values from each one of the files and upload it to website ONE FILE AT A TIME.

My code is not working, and I am assuming this is because of the callback problem..

Could anybody help?

Edit: I also added my uploadFile function. I very much appreciate your help.

```
for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            //console.log(fileList[i]["file"]);
            var reader = new FileReader();

            var f = fileList[i]["file"];
            //var fName = fileList[i]["fileName"];
            var excelObject = fileList[i];

            reader.onload = function(ev) {

                var data = ev.target.result;
                if(!rABS) data = new Uint8Array(data);

                var wb = XLSX.read(data, {type: rABS ? 'binary' : 'array'});

                var einAddress = "B3";
                var engCodeAddress = "B1";
                var goAddress = "B2";
                var errMsg = tabName + " tab or required value is missing";

                    // Worksheet with the necessary info
                try{
                    var ws =  wb.Sheets[tabName];
                    var ein_cell = ws[einAddress];
                    ein = (ein_cell ? ein_cell.v.toString() : undefined);

                    var eng_cell = ws[engCodeAddress];
                    engCode = (eng_cell ? eng_cell.v.toString() : undefined);

                    var go_cell = ws[goAddress];
                    goLocator = (go_cell ? go_cell.v.toString() : undefined);

                    if(ein == undefined || engCode == undefined || goLocator == undefined){
                        hasValues = false;
                    }

                    excelObject["EngagementCode"] = engCode;
                    excelObject["GoSystem"] = goLocator;
                    excelObject["EIN"] = ein;

                    if(hasValues && isValid){
                        uploadFile(fileList[i], userInfo);
                    } else {
                        noValueErrorHandler(errMsg);
                    }

                } catch(err){
                    hasValues = false;
                }

            };

            if(rABS) reader.readAsBinaryString(f); else reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);

        } 


function uploadFile(f, userInfo) {

// Define the folder path for this example.
var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = listName;

// Get info of the file to be uploaded
var file = f;
var fileInput = file["file"];
var newName = file["fileName"];
var ein = file["EIN"];
var engCode = file["EngagementCode"];
var email = userInfo;
var goLocator = file["GoSystem"];
console.log("file: " + file);

// Get the server URL.
var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/StatusTracker";

// Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
// Get the local file as an array buffer.
var getFile = getFileBuffer(fileInput);
getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

    // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
    var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer, newName);
    addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {

        // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
        var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
        getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {

            // Change the display name and title of the list item.
            var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
            changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                processedCount += 1;
                if (processedCount < fileCount) {

                    uploadFile(fileList[processedCount], email);

                } else if (processedCount == fileCount){
                    $("#dropbox").text("Done, drop your next file");
                    $("#ADMNGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                    fileList = [];
                    alert("Total of " + processedCount + " items are processed!");
                }



                // Refresh kendo grid and change back the message and empty fileList
                //$("#dropbox").text("Drag your Fund/Lower Tier workpaper here ...");
                //location.reload(true);

            });
            changeItem.fail(onError);
        });
        getItem.fail(onError);
    });
    addFile.fail(onError);
});
getFile.fail(onError);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might put the whole thing into an `async` function and `await` a `Promise` for each iteration, forcing the files to be processed in serial. You didn't post your `uploadFile`, but if you have it return a `Promise` that resolves once it's done, you could do the following:

```
async fn() {
  for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //console.log(fileList[i]["file"]);
      var reader = new FileReader();

      var f = fileList[i]["file"];
      //var fName = fileList[i]["fileName"];
      var excelObject = fileList[i];

      reader.onload = function(ev) {

        var data = ev.target.result;
        if (!rABS) data = new Uint8Array(data);

        var wb = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: rABS ? 'binary' : 'array'
        });

        var einAddress = "B3";
        var engCodeAddress = "B1";
        var goAddress = "B2";
        var errMsg = tabName + " tab or required value is missing";

        // Worksheet with the necessary info
        try {
          var ws = wb.Sheets[tabName];
          var ein_cell = ws[einAddress];
          ein = (ein_cell ? ein_cell.v.toString() : undefined);

          var eng_cell = ws[engCodeAddress];
          engCode = (eng_cell ? eng_cell.v.toString() : undefined);

          var go_cell = ws[goAddress];
          goLocator = (go_cell ? go_cell.v.toString() : undefined);

          if (ein == undefined || engCode == undefined || goLocator == undefined) {
            hasValues = false;
          }

          excelObject["EngagementCode"] = engCode;
          excelObject["GoSystem"] = goLocator;
          excelObject["EIN"] = ein;

          if (hasValues && isValid) {
            uploadFile(fileList[i], userInfo)
              .then(resolve);
          } else {
            noValueErrorHandler(errMsg);
            reject();
          }

        } catch (err) {
          hasValues = false;
          reject();
        }

      };

      if (rABS) reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
      else reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very very much, I added my uploadFile function. Could you please take a look at it and teach me how to return promise??

Comment: You're falling into the promise-as-callback antipattern there. If you chain the promises properly and call `.then` on them, you can simply `return` the promise at the top level of `uploadFile` - `return getFile.then(...`

Comment: I really appreciate help, but would you mind editing your answer and show me the code? I am really confused here..

Comment: You need to ensure that `getFileBuffer`, `addFileToFolder` and so on return Promises, then `return` them on each link of the promise chain, rather than using them like callbacks. `return addFileToFolder...`, `return getItem...` and so on